# Why do I have low FPS on a good PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, graphics-card, performance

So I was playing Minecraft with shaders at around 50 - 80 fps 10 minutes ago. then i disconnected and minimised minecraft so I could make a new wallpaper in paint.net. Then when I got back into my server, I was getting around 30 FPS!
The only other applications running in the background are Skype and my server.

System specifications:

- Windows 10
- GeForce GTX 970
- Intel Core I5
- 8192 MiB RAM (8 GB)
- 60 Hz Monitor

Comment: Did you fullscreen Minecraft with F11 key (or Fn + F11 on some laptops or Macs) or you simply maximized the window?

Comment: 30 fps is good. fps isn't a problem until it hits below 10

Comment: @Fennekin did you even read the question? He should be getting upwards of 60fps with that system, even with shaders. And *cinematic* 30fps is not acceptable as a PC gamer.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft (and Java in general) uses a LOT of RAM and if you are using any mods(such as the shaders) there might be some memory leaks which lead to the GC firing more often as the allocated memory gets full. The GC(Garbage collector) requires a lot of processing power and stalls the memory for a bit as it is cleaning big chunks of data at once. If you are unsure about the memory press `F3` and check what the memory usage says.

Your problem could also be caused by other factors because the GTX 970 is a pretty powerful graphics card and that FPS count even with shaders enabled is not OK. Check that your graphics card drivers are up to date and if they are not update them. Also check what is your memory and CPU usage in the task manager.

And also please post what version of Minecraft are you playing on, any and all installed mods with versions and version of JRE(with `Win`+`R`, `"cmd"`, `Enter`, `"java -version"` ) you are using.

PS: Check the options if you are not limiting the FPS and using advanced OGL with VSync off

Comment: "Check the options if you are not limiting the FPS" he probably isn't, as he said that prior to fps dropping to 30, he was running at 50-80. If he had been limiting fps, he probably wouldn't have had correct fps in the beginning.

Comment: @Lysarion he could be limiting the FPS to 120 which in some cases caused lower FPS than when it was set to unlimited